# how to get Http Request from website by Windows App in C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, httprequest

I send one Http Request for specific URL and want That URL send me feedback through a response. I know how to send a request but I don't know how I can get a response from that URL

thanks!

Comment: Look into `HttpClient` Or more generally "How do I make an HTTP request in C#"

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+store+app+http+request

Comment: First result: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh781239.aspx

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It's a little different for Windows Store Apps.  That's still no excuse, though.

Comment: i send request to url but cant get request from that Url!

Comment: @AftabGarm my crystal ball says you have a bug in line 253.

Comment: What happens? Does it explode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code to use `HTTPClient` class in c#. My scenario is to send a request using a `async void` method and if any error happens show the error message in windows store app.

In order to use HTTPClient class you have to use `System.Net.Http` name space. And in order to display simple messagebox, you have to use `Windows.UI.Popups` namesapce.
here is the code

```
using System.Net.Http; //this is for HTTPClient class
using Windows.UI.Popups //this is for Messagebox popup.

private async void getResponse()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient htClient = new HttpClient();
                string webUri = "www.google.com" //replace ur request web URI here
                string result = await htClient.GetStringAsync(webUri);
                //Form here you can code to extract the web response.
                //result is the web response string
            }
            catch (Exception c)
            {
                messageBox(c.Message);

            }
        }
//this is the method to show messagebox popup
protected async void messageBox(string msg)
        {
            var msgDlg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(msg);
            msgDlg.DefaultCommandIndex = 1;
            await msgDlg.ShowAsync();
        }
```